# How to use TryUpdateModel to pick form values in asp.net website using MasterPage

Tags: asp.net

Recently I tried to use the TryUpdateModel to get the value of the control in a form, but the trouble is that I use the MasterPage in my asp.net website, I found that although I can set the "ClinetIDMode" to Static to ensure that the control ID will not become MainContent_USER_NAME.But I found FormValueProvider match the name of control rather than id, and there is no such a "ClientNameMode"  attribute can be set to Static, so the name of the control can only be something like "ctl00$MainContent$USER_NAME".
How to solve this problem?Please help me.And my aspx and cs file:

Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div>    
    UserName:<asp:TextBox ID="USER_NAME" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add a user" OnClick="Button1_Click" />    
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        USER_INFO u = new USER_INFO();

        IValueProvider p = new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext);

        if (TryUpdateModel(u, p))
        {
            String name = u.USER_NAME;//can't pick the value
            db.USER_INFO.Add(u);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you set the name="USER_NAME" for your text box?

Comment: Yes,I tried this.The name property of the input control is still something like ctl00$MainContent$USER_NAME..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution.I can write a little front-end code to set the `name` equal to `id`.

```
 <script>
     $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         $(this).attr("name", id);
     });
 </script>
```

And don't forget to set Page's `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```